# Word, Expand To Fill Table With Dots

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
                        Header1 Header2
I am a piece of text    Value1  Value2
```

I am trying to modify the table so that dots consume all the whitespace within the table, with the margins being at 0. The table is autosized to fit the window to expand/contract with different values. The expected results would look similar to the following:

```
                       Header1  Header2
I am a piece of text....Value1...Value2
```

The content in the table is constantly changing, thus I don't want to type in the dots but have the whitespace replaced with dots. Is this possible in MS Word?

Comment: your example shows that not all spaces are replaced by dots ... how do you decide which spaces to replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (too?) simple method can be used if the table's sizes are fixed
as regarding row height and columns widths and the text is
left-justified.

You can then fill up the empty cells with dots, and afterward
add you text at the beginning.
This will "push" the ending dots out of the
cell so they are no longer displayed.

Comment: do you have to setup wrapping up something as well? It just pushes them down to the next line it seems.

Comment: This means that the sizes are not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This might help - it'll change the value of "TAB" key.
You should just convert the table into text, while using tabs as your divider ( not other characters like , - | etc. )

1. Select Layout or Page Layout.
2. Select the Paragraph dialog launcher  and then select Tabs.
3. Add or select a tab stop, and then select leader character option under Leader you want displayed.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/show-dots-or-leaders-between-tabs-c80b62d0-2244-4078-95bd-8c82f91440ba